# Email UID_VALIDITY - moving emails from spam/archive to main inbox

Tags: email, imap, imaplib

Edit: Looks like I was confused about what triggers the UID_VALIDITY to be re-assigned. I thought that moving/deleting emails might cause other email UIDs to change and thus change the UID_VALIDITY [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593869/unique-email-identifiers-with-imap#comment18635963_13594601). Probably a better question is whether moving emails from one folder to another will cause the UID_VALIDITY of the destination folder to be re-assigned.

Original question:

I've read that moving an email from one inbox/folder to another will trigger the email server to re-assign all email UIDs and change the UID_VALIDITY value. Is this also true for moving emails between folders that Outlook creates? I am using Outlook with Python imaplib library and I have some emails that I accidentally archived and some emails in spam that I would like to move back to the main inbox while keeping the UID_VALIDITY the same. Are the spam/archive folders real folders or does Outlook use some sort of filter/flag to create the spam/archive folders? If simply moving the emails from spam/archive will trigger the UID to change, is there some other way of copying/moving these emails while keeping the UID_VALIDITY value the same?

Due to company restrictions, I cannot easily test this with a test account so any ideas would be welcomed.

Related but pretty general: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37269897/how-to-use-uidvalidity-and-highestmodseq-of-an-imap-folder-to-sync-email), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593869/unique-email-identifiers-with-imap#comment18635963_13594601), [link3](https://serverfault.com/questions/422803/uid-uniqueness-of-imap-mails), [link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58467415/uid-of-email-in-imap-which-does-not-change-if-mail-get-moved)

Comment: No, that is not true. Nothing could be further from the truth.

Comment: UIDVALIDITY is for a *folder*.  UIDs are for messages.  They are not preserved across folder moves, ever, as messages _must_be assigned new UIDs when they [re]appear in a folder.

Comment: @arnt could you elaborate which part I got wrong or what the truth should be? Thanks

Comment: @Max So if I move an email from folder A to folder B, the email's UID will change. That I understand. But will folder A's UID VALIDITY change?

Comment: @Amy Generally no.  UIDVALIDITY generally only changes if the server has a catastrophic error and needs to rebuild the database (or server software change or major upgrade) or someone has renamed the folders so you’re looking at a new folder.  (Eg, someone renamed Folder X to A, and Folder B to X, so you’re seeing a different folder.)   It is basically a serial number to let you know if you have to drop your cache.

Comment: @Max thanks very much for the insight. I misunderstood what would cause the UIDVALIDITY to change.